# Every rational function which is holomorphic on Riemann Sphere($\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$)

Tags: riemann-surfaces

could any one give me a hint how to show Every rational function which is holomorphic on every point of Riemann Sphere( $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$) must be constant?(with out applying Maximum Modulas Theorem).
Thank you.

Comment: Does using the fact that the Riemann sphere is compact count as using the maximum modulus principle?

Answer (score 4):

If a function is analytic on the sphere at $\infty$, it is bounded in an neighborhood of $\infty$.  Consequently, it is bounded globally, since the complement of a neighbhorhood at $\infty$ is compact.  Now invoke Liouville's theorem; the functon must be constant.

Comment: why it is bounded in an neighborhood of $\infty$?

Comment: If it is analytic at $\infty$, it is continuous there and it therefore bounded there.  Note that a polynomial has a pole at $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere.